# Darlington pair

Tags: transistors, darlington

[image]

Here, the first transistor t1, is to be connected in CC configuration. Doesn't that mean that the collector of the first transistor should be grounded?

Also, the collector doesn't seem to be *"common"* to the emitter and base as is implied from common collector configuration

Comment: I don't know what your question actually is. I tried. But it's obscure to me. Could you write more about your thoughts? (And tell me which is the "first" transistor and which isn't.)

Comment: @jonk, somebody probably told them that a Darlington pair is a two-stage amplifier with a CC stage and a CE stage, which is a somewhat reasonable way to look at it if the overall darlington is in CE configuration.

Comment: @ThePhoton That depends, at least in part, how the Darlington itself is applied in a circuit, though. Certainly, you can see the left side BJT as an emitter follower (therefore a CC arrangment.) But the overall analysis depends how it is used in a circuit -- certainly as it applies to the right side/pair combo arrangement.

Comment: @jonk, yes, but those subtleties are often forgotten by learners.

Comment: @jonk read my edited question

Comment: @user29463 You have some decent discussions in the answers below. One thing I note about your question is that you "imagine" that a CC arrangement has its collector grounded. It's usually the case that the collector is tied to a low-impedance voltage source for CC. But CC is also known as "emitter follower," too. And that's probably the better way to see \$T_1\$ here. \$T_1\$'s emitter will *follow* its base voltage and, in doing so, will draw current from its collector so that its emitter can source lots more current than supplied to its base.

Comment: @jonk yes you are right... I used to think that in CC the collecter has to be grounded, in CE the emmiter and CB the base. So basically, the common terminal can be connected to any source depending on the requirement of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

CC does not apply to the transistor alone. It applies to pin shared by the input and output signal when a supply is connected with bias resistors.

For example below used as a Common Base.
 [image]

```
Input Output  Config.
B     C       CE
E     C       CB
B     E       CC
```

"Ground" is simply a term meaning a local voltage source/sink=0V  ( ie low impedance)  It could be floating wr.t. earth ground.

A CC could use V+ and V- and the signal could be ground referenced for example and none of the pins of the transistor would be grounded with input on base and resistors on collectors and emitter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvwufs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "CC does not apply to the transistor alone. It applies to pin shared by the input and output signal when a supply is connected with bias resistors." But for t1, the input and the output pins is not having any connection with the collecter of t1

Comment: That's incorrect, a discrete part with no inputs or outputs given has no configuration. A Darlington like a single NPN may be used in all 3 configurations. As shown it is simply a transistor with hFE ^2 and an extra diode drop. Not exactly but in any case it can be used as CB,CE,CC

Comment: T1 is part of T2 and may be treated as a single transistor for AC analysis.  and thus it is not CC, NOR should the 1st transistor E be grounded

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4d3W.png

Answer (score 1):

The terms 'common collector/emitter/base' are often used to describe what amplifying characteristic of the transistor is being emphasised.

Darlingtons were invented to mitigate one of the main problems of high current transistors, which was low Hfe, or beta. Whereas 'signal' transistors (say <100mA) would usually have a beta of >100, 'power' transistors might have a beta only in the 10s.

To this end, a high gain transistor is placed as a *current amplifier* on the base of a power transistor. Its purpose is solely to provide an output current of beta*base_current from its emitter, to bias the following power transistor, without reference to what its collector is doing (as long as the collector voltage is high enough).

A 'base to emitter current amplifier' is more succinctly termed a 'common collector' amplifier.

Similarly, it's less of a mouthful to refer to an 'emitter to collector voltage amplifier' as a 'common base' stage.

Fun fact - patent US2663806 was filed in 1952 by Sidney Darlington of Nokia Bell Labs.

Comment: With other words: The main purpose of the Darlington pair is to form a new "power transistor" with an acceptable large input resistance (comparable small input current).

Comment: @LvW Exactly right, I might go and look and see if there's a patent by Mr Darlington. The main drawback is of course limiting the minimum VCEsat, though lousy speed comes a close second.

Comment: Neil thanks for the fun fact

Comment: Thanks for the patent addition. It seems to me, though, that patenting the idea of adding another BJT to provide additional current gain (even back in 1952) is like patenting the idea of using a collector resistor to cause a voltage drop due to the collector current and taking a signal from there. Kind of "obvious to experienced practitioners of the art." But Microsoft patented the use of using XOR for pixels because a second XOR restores the original pixel. And that's obvious to anyone. So, oh well.

Comment: @jonk One test for a patent being non-obvious is whether it fulfills a 'long felt want'. It's very difficult to cast your mind back to 1952, and see with naive eyes. I'm sure that MOAR BETA was such a desired goal. Until you've spent a few years prosecuting and defending them, the shenanagins that go on around them can be hard to believe.